# Form is not updating, after custom class event is fired

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, class, process, event-handling

I'm having an issue where my main form isn't updating even though I see the event fire off.  Let me explain the situation and share some of my code which I'm sure will be horrible since I'm an amateur.

I created a class to take in the settings for running a process in the background.  I add some custom events in that class so I could use that in my form instead of a timer.

I put a break on the two subs for that handle those events and I see them get kicked off as soon as an install starts.

I look at the data and it's coming across and no exceptions are thrown.

At first I thought it was because the datagridview had some latency issues.  I set that to be double buffered through some tricks I found but it didn't matter.  There was still a roughly 10 second delay before the data showed up in the datagrid.

I thought about it and decided I really didn't need a datagridview and replaced the control with a multiline textbox, but it didn't make a difference.  It's still taking 10 seconds or longer to show updates to the form/textbox.

I've included some of my code below.

```
Public Shared WithEvents np As NewProcess
```

---

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Try
            np = New NewProcess
            AddHandler np.InstallFinished, AddressOf np_InstallFinished
            AddHandler np.InstallStarted, AddressOf np_InstallStarted
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub
```

---

```
Protected Sub np_InstallFinished(ByVal Description As String, ByVal ExitCode As Integer)
    InstallInProcess = False

    If Not Description = Nothing Then
        If Not ExitCode = Nothing Then
            AddLog(String.Format("Completed install of {0} ({1}).", Description, ExitCode))
        Else
            AddLog(String.Format("Completed install of {0}.", Description))
        End If
    End If
    RefreshButtons()
    UpdateListofApps()
    np.Dispose()
End Sub
```

---

```
Protected Sub np_InstallStarted(ByVal Description As String)
    InstallInProcess = True

    If Not Description = Nothing Then AddLog(String.Format("Started the install of {0}.", Description))
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Class NewProcess
    Dim ProcessName As String
    Dim ProcessVisibile As Boolean
    Dim Arguments As String
    Dim WaitforExit As Boolean
    Dim Description As String
    Dim ShellExecute As Boolean
    Dim EC As Integer = Nothing 'Exit Code
    Private IsBusy As Boolean = Nothing
    Dim th As Threading.Thread

    Public Event InstallFinished(ByVal Description As String, ByVal ExitCode As Integer)

    Public Event InstallStarted(ByVal Description As String)

    Public Function Busy() As Boolean
        If IsBusy = Nothing Then Return False
        Return IsBusy
    End Function

    Public Function ExitCode() As Integer
        Return EC
    End Function

    Public Function ProcessDescription() As String
        Return Description
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Starts a new multithreaded process.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="path">Path of the File to run</param>
    ''' <param name="Visible">Should application be visible?</param>
    ''' <param name="Arg">Arguments</param>
    ''' <param name="WaitforExit">Wait for application to exit?</param>
    ''' <param name="Description">Description that will show up in logs</param>
    ''' <remarks>Starts a new multithreaded process.</remarks>
    Public Sub StartProcess(ByVal path As String, ByVal Visible As Boolean, Optional ByVal Arg As String = Nothing, Optional ByVal WaitforExit As Boolean = False, Optional ByVal Description As String = Nothing)

        Try
            Me.ProcessName = path
            Me.ProcessVisibile = Visible
            If Arguments = Nothing Then Me.Arguments = Arg
            Me.Description = Description
            Me.WaitforExit = WaitforExit

            If IsBusy And WaitforExit Then
                MessageBox.Show("Another install is already in process, please wait for previous install to finish.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If Not fn_FileExists(ProcessName) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Could not find file " & ProcessName & ".", "Could not start process because file is missing.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
                Exit Sub
            End If

            th = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf NewThread)

            With th
                .IsBackground = True
                If Not Description Is Nothing Then .Name = Description
                .Start()
            End With
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub NewThread()
        Dim p As Process

        Try
            p = New Process

            With p
                .EnableRaisingEvents = True
                .StartInfo.Arguments = Arguments
                .StartInfo.FileName = ProcessName
                .StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = ProcessVisibile
            End With

            If ProcessVisibile Then
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            Else
                p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
            End If

            p.Start()
            IsBusy = True
            RaiseEvent InstallStarted(Description)

            If WaitforExit Then
                Do While p.HasExited = False
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                Loop
                IsBusy = False
                RaiseEvent InstallFinished(Description, p.ExitCode)
            End If

            EC = p.ExitCode  

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose()
        ProcessName = Nothing
        ProcessVisibile = Nothing
        Arguments = Nothing
        WaitforExit = Nothing
        Description = Nothing
        EC = Nothing
        InstallInProcess = Nothing
        th.Join()
        MemoryManagement.FlushMemory()
    End Sub

End Class
```

---

```
Sub AddLog(ByVal s As String)
    Try

        s = String.Format("[{0}] {1}", TimeOfDay.ToShortTimeString, s)

        Form1.tbLogs.AppendText(s & vbCrLf)

        Using st As New StreamWriter(LogFilePath, True)
            st.WriteLine(s)
            st.Flush()
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any idea's?  I'm at a complete loss.

I've tried adding application.doevents, me.refresh and quite a few other things :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    Form1.tbLogs.AppendText(s & vbCrLf)
```

Standard VB.NET trap.  Form1 is a class name, not a reference to the form.  Unfortunately, VB.NET implemented an anachronism from VB6 where that was legal.  It however falls apart when you use threads.  You'll get *another* form object automatically created, one that isn't visible because its Show() method was never called.  Otherwise dead as a doornail since the thread is not pumping a message loop.

You'll need to pass a reference to the actual form object that the user is looking at to the worker class.  The value of Me in the Form1 code.  You will also have to use Control.Invoke since it isn't legal to update controls from another thread.  I recommend you fire an event instead, one that Form1 can subscribe to, so that your worker class isn't infected with implementation details of the UI.

Comment: I sort of understand what your saying but I thought since I added the handler in form1, and the events in form1 that it would actually happen there and not create a new form1 object.

The Addlog function where the following code happens is a module.

Form1.tbLogs.AppendText(s & vbCrLf)

So when you say I need to pass a reference to the actual form object how would I do that?

Yesterday I did try in the event, since it's in the form to do me.tblogs.appendtext but it had the same effect.

Comment: It is a very basic OOP issue, hard to get you up to speed on that in a comment box.  The Q&D fix is to use Application.OpenForms(0) instead, that's a reference to the first form that was created.  Probably Form1.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks Hans.  Does that explain why it shows up in the textbox after 10 seconds?

I mean if I'm reading you correctly it wouldn't update at all, because it would interacting with a different object completely.

Comment: You got me pointed in the right direction.  Thanks Hans.  This was my solution:

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

1. First make it work without threads. (Ironical you call yourself an amateur, It so happened I only learned to do that after I was past the 'amateur' stage)
2. Don't try to update the GUI Controls from a background thread. That's forbidden in windows. I'm not sure that's what you do (no VB guru), but it sure looks like it.
3. Use the .net `BackgroundWorker` class. It has builtin functionality to talk back to the main thread from a background thread. It's not perfect but a good start.

Answer (score 1):

You got me pointed in the right direction.  Thanks Hans.  This was my solution:

```
Private Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)

    If Me.tbLogs.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        Me.tbLogs.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub np_InstallStarted(ByVal Description As String)
    InstallInProcess = True
    If Me.tbLogs.Text = "" Then
        SetText(String.Format("[{0}] Started the install of {1}.{2}", TimeOfDay.ToShortTimeString, Description, vbCrLf))
    Else
        SetText(tbLogs.Text & vbCrLf & String.Format("[{0}] Started the install of {1}.{2}", TimeOfDay.ToShortTimeString, Description, vbCrLf))
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub np_InstallFinished(ByVal [Description] As String, ByVal [ExitCode] As Integer)
    InstallInProcess = False

    If Not Description = Nothing Then
        If Not ExitCode = Nothing Then
            SetText(tbLogs.Text & vbCrLf & String.Format("[{0}] Completed install of {1} ({2}).{3}", TimeOfDay.ToShortTimeString, Description, ExitCode, vbCrLf))
        Else
            SetText(tbLogs.Text & vbCrLf & String.Format("[{0}] Completed install of {1}.{3}", TimeOfDay.ToShortTimeString, Description, vbCrLf))
        End If
    End If
    RefreshButtons()
    UpdateListofApps()
    np.Dispose()
End Sub
```

So when the event kicks off that the install has started or finished, I use the SetText to update the log on the original form.

Problem is I posted that original post as an "unregistered user" so now I'm trying to figure out a way to say the question was answered.  Thanks again for your help!